# Regex: Tightening up an IPv4 regex to omit ESMTPSA id?

Tags: regex, ip-address, ipv4

An ESMTPSA id is a string that looks something like:

```
w12sm4743917pbs.68.2015.06.04.16.21.51
```

It can appear in the Received: from header in in email, such as in the following example:

```
Received: from [192.168.0.140] (n11649196059.netvigator.com. [116.49.196.59])
        by mx.google.com with ESMTPSA id w12sm4743917pbs.68.2015.06.04.16.21.51
        for <myemailaddress@gmail.com>
        (version=TLSv1.2 cipher=ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 bits=128/128);
        Thu, 04 Jun 2015 16:21:52 -0700 (PDT)
```

I have the following regex which works well at extracting IPv4 addess from such a header:

```
d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}
```

Problem is, it's also extracting a chunk of the ESMTPSA id: **015.06.04.16**. See it in action [here](https://regex101.com/r/qP6uI5/1).

How would we tighten the regex up so that it only extracts the IPv4 address? Note: the addresses are *not* always in square brackets, as in the above example. I'm using Python and I know I could use the `ipaddress` module to validate all matches, but it will be far more convenient for me to not match in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[^\.\d]\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}[^\.\d]
```

and trim 1 symbol from start and end of string (or use capturing groups)

**PS** or simply use your first regexp after my

**PS2** with capturing group

```
[^\.\d](\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})[^\.\d]
```

most of regexp tools allow you to get capturing group by number(in order) like \1 or similar

Comment: it checks that before and after ip not number and not "."

Comment: I see the logic in your expansion of the regex, but it doesn't work for me (neither your original not your update): https://regex101.com/r/yP2rG2/1 When you say trim one symbol, to what symbols are you referring?

Comment: this regexp will match one simbol before ip and one after

Comment: Ok since it includes the square brackets around the IP address, this is what you mean about trimming one character from either side.

Comment: It includes the square brackets around the IP address though, right?

Comment: u can solve this problem with two methods: 1) use capturing group 2) launch your inital regexp (listed in question) on results of my my regexp